# How to decide number of site limit in IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

How to decide number of site limit in IIS 7 if given seprate application pool per site for different version?
 Any one know it?
- Kartik

Comment: Subject says IIS 6, body says IIS 7

Comment: Shouldn't this question be asked on serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on number of sites IIS can host. It all depends on the number of requests handled by your server and the server configurations.

It has less to do with Application pool per site.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of factors, how often the sites are recycling, how much RAM the server has, the traffic of the sites.